# Solve folding paper challenge

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-lists

Ok so I'm trying to solve this logical question in a pythonic way, but I'm not very good. Here goes:

You have a piece of paper with a list of numbers on it like so:

1 2 3 4 | 5 6 7 8

If you fold the paper from the left to the right down the middle, you get this order:

(first number is on top)
(4,5) (3,6) (2,7) (1,8)

And you can fold it one more time either way, and get a new order (right-to-left example):

(first number on top, then second below, ...etc)
(8,1,4,5) (7,2,3,6)

I started with seeing how to fold the paper and get a list of lists with the correct order:

```
paper = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

half_paper = len(paper)/2
s = paper[:half_paper]
e = paper[half_paper:]
middle_distance = 0

final_list = []

for l in range(half_paper):
    print l
    m = [s[half_paper-middle_distance-1],e[middle_distance-half_paper]]
    final_list.append(m)     
    middle_distance += 1

 print final_list
```

This works, results in [[4,5], [3,6], [2,7], [1,8]] (fold left to right). But now I'm stuck. I've been trying to figure out a way to use list comprehension to apply the logic on the final_list result, so I can "fold" the paper again to get a result of [[5,4,1,8], [6,3,2,7]] (fold left to right again, or if fold right to left [[8,1,4,5], [7,2,3,6]]).

I'm not sure how to use list comprehension to do what i did in the for loop, on a list of lists and result in a list of lists. Any ideas to get me started?

Comment: sorry for the multiple edits, just getting my number folding logic right

Comment: I don't think you really want a list of lists the first time around, or else you'd have illustrated a list of list of lists in your expected results for the second iteration. :) So why not just write the code so that it produces a flat list? Or else explicitly flatten it afterwards?

Comment: i specifically want to provide a list of lists because the result needs to reflect the order of the numbers in references to closest to you and furthest from you. ex [5,4,1,8] and [6,3,2,7] both represent a "column" of numbers that have been folded on themselves from the original 8 columns. in the first one, 5 is the top fold, 4, the next fold down in that column, etc... and this should work for any even list of #'s. so 128 numbers should fold down to a list of two lists with the proper column order.

Comment: @karl i started providing a flat list, but it doesn't reflect order. and i don't need anything deeper than a list in a list, not a list in a list in a list in... it will always be a list of numbers in a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
l1,l2 = l[:len(l)/2], l[len(l)/2:]
l = [ [x,y] for x,y in zip (l1, l2[::-1])]
for i in range(len(l)):
        if isinstance(l[i][0], list):
                l[i] = [x for item in l[i] for x in item]
print l

l1,l2 = l[:len(l)/2], l[len(l)/2:]
l = [ [x,y] for x,y in zip (l1, l2[::-1])]
for i in range(len(l)):
        if isinstance(l[i][0], list):
                l[i] = [x for item in l[i] for x in item]
print l
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 8], [2, 7], [3, 6], [4, 5]]
[[1, 8, 4, 5], [2, 7, 3, 6]]
```

Comment: can i reiterate that on itself? so if i have a list that is super long [1, 2, .. 255, 256]?

Comment: that makes lists in lists in lists.... I want my end result to be one list of two lists at the end of the iteration. +1 for the help.

Comment: oh awesome, it's going to take me like 10 minutes to try this in my script, but if it comes back right you will totally get the answer check. i'll probably just test your script as is, and if it works, check you off, and then work it into my script (late, tired, should goto bed). thanks man, i'll check you off in a few when i test.

Comment: i'm checkin' you off.. but, your script doesn't provide any stop features/exception grabs. so i could reiterate this but it would fail at some point no matter what. (be boss and tell me what's up)